# Raw SVG using raw-loader, keep getting inline SVG

Tags: svg, vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli, raw-loader

I'm trying to display raw svg in the Vue component using raw-loader. 
However, the svg is always inlined no matter what I do. Here's my code:

```
<template>
    <div v-html="svg"></div>
</template>

<script>
import svg from 'raw-loader!@/assets/images/image.svg';
export default {
    data () {
        return {
              svg
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

I understand this is due to `vue-cli` webpack's config `webpack.base.conf.js`:

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  },
```

I've tried to add a new loader rule to load raw files if I append `?raw` to them but that does not work either:

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?raw)$/,
    loader: 'raw-loader',
  },
```

I'm using:

- vue-cli@2.9.2
- vue@2.5.2

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of those two loaders?

Comment: If that doesn't work, try changing the `url-loader` to `test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?(?!raw).*)?$/,` and try to use `?raw` back again.

Comment: @acdcjunior Thanks, none of these work. Switching the order was my first try actually. It seems to me that the loader does not care about the query string... so if you require file.svg or file.svg?something, it always looks at the file.svg ...